# How can I mirror bone rotations?

Tags: rigging, mirror

I have a rigged character. And like most character models, I have modeled it in the "T-pose". Now I want to create an idle animation, so the arms need to be resting by the character's side. I selected both the upper arms and tried to rotate the arms simultaneously. This causes the one arm to lift and the other one to rest

Like so:
[image: Character]

I was wondering if there's a way to mirror the rotation? Most of the material I could find regarding this simply "Flips" the armature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>R</kbd> to set rotation mode

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to set mirror mode

In this case <kbd>X</kbd> key twice

You'll see two red lines cross over your character in front view.